# Build native-image using Maven with Micronaut framework

Tags: micronaut

I just downloaded a new project from https://micronaut.io/launch for java 8 with maven with features:

- AWS Lambda
- AWS Lambda Runtime
- Graalvm support

In the readme.md it actually only shows build instructions to get a native-image with gradle. But how do you do it with Maven?

Answer (score 1):

`./mvnw package -Dpackaging=native-image`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29021702)

Comment: @mufazmi have you used Micronaut? this _is_ the answer to the question